# Get user by query string in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get user by id or by some parameters but the response always be all the users. I use the get method without any query just the test api without any authentication.

code :

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.query.id);
    if (!user)
        return res.status(404).send("The user with the given ID was not found.");
    res.send(user);
});
```

url: http://localhost:4000/api/user?id=5e6e8159fd64bf27042a8838

the response always get all user

any help plz

Comment: I assume you use mongoose and according to the documentation at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById mongoose translates findById(undefined) to findOne(null) which returns arbitary documents. So my guess is that req.query.id is undefined. Im not an express expert so you might need to check express docs on how to get query params since i know there are multiple ways.

Comment: What is the result of console.log(req.query.id)?

Answer (score 0):

@main.c is right. What you want to do is `req.params.id`,

req,query is used when you need to extract query properties like

`/:id?sort=asc&discount=50`

Then you can do `req.query.sort` or `req.query.discount`

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your code is your route looks like `router.get('/:id')`.

This means the URL should be something like `/user/{id}`.

The URL you are firing which is `/user?id={id}` might not be hitting this route as it does not have `{id}` route param in it.

The actual URL that'd hit this route is -

`http://localhost:4000/api/user/5e6e8159fd64bf27042a8838`.

And the way you should read id is `request.params.id`

I suspect `/user` route is pointing to get all users API which is why you are getting all users in response.